# Ckan backup and restore

Tags: python, ckan

I'm trying to write some documentation on how to restore a CKAN instance in my organization.

I have backuped and restored successfully CKAN database and resources folder but i don't know what i have to do with datastore db.

Which is the best practice?

Use `pg_dump` to dump the database or initialize it from the resources folder (if there is a way)?

Thanks.
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backup CKAN's databases (the main one and Datastore one if you use it) with `pg_dump`. If you use Filestore then you need to take a backup copy of the files in the directory specified by ckan.storage_path (default is `/var/lib/ckan/default`)

Restore the database backups (after doing `createdb`) using `psql -f`. Then run `paster db upgrade` just in case it was from an older ckan version. Then `paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild`. In an emergency use `rebuild_fast` instead of `rebuild`, but I think it might create some duplicates entries, so to be certain you could then do `rebuild -r` to do it again carefully but slowly.

> initialize [the datastore database] from the resources folder (if there is a way)

I don't think the CKAN Data Pusher has a command-line interface to push all the resources. It would be a good plan for you to write one and submit a PR for everyone's benefit.

Comment: Thanks @D Read, then there is no "just cooked" way to restore the datastore database from resurces without a dump?

Comment: What's this 'resources folder' you refer to?

Comment: 'resurces' is the filesystem folder where ckan put dataset attachments (http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/filestore.html). Restoring it and ckan database return a ckan instance replicated from my production server but datastore is empty because datapusher is triggered only when an attachment is saved.